# Ubuntu 12.04 and NetBeans 7.2?

Tags: netbeans

I installed 12.04, then I installed all updates in Update Manager. After this, I installed all the necessary applications and installed NetBeans 7.2. But now I am trying to launch it from Dash home and it does not start. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

I installed Netbeans 7.2 on a clean new installation of Ubuntu 12.04 and found, that it was not available in the dash at all. But it should have created a link on the desktop. Try that one and lock it to the launcher if its running.

If that does not help you should try to start it from a terminal and find out, if the startup has any problems or errors in the output there:

```
~/netbeans-7.2/bin/netbeans
```

If you chose to install it into another folder you need to change the path according to your installation path.

Comment: This is what i did and what happened: root@arvigiezasss-pc:/usr/local# ~/netbeans-7.2/bin/netbeans
bash: /root/netbeans-7.2/bin/netbeans: No such file or directory

Comment: @user73795 you should not run Netbeans as root.

Comment: Hello again. NetBeans 7.2  that i downloaded and installed from official website still do not run, but i installed older version from Software Center and it runs. But the problem with this version is that it has no C++ integrated and this is the language i want to use. Also i can't remove NetBeans 7.2. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Theank you, but i solved the question and do not need your help anymore. Good bye.

Comment: @user73795 - In order to improve the AskUbuntu community, you should post your solution as an answer, then mark it as answered, so that others that have the same (or a similar) issue can know what you did.

Comment: @user73795 I would like to know how did you solve the problem. Because I want to install NetBeans on my laptop :)