# C++ Development Cinder/Visual Studio

Tags: 12.04, development, c++

I'm currently taking a Data Structures course that involves the development of C++ applications using microsoft visual studio express c++, an application called Cinder, and we turn in assignments via GitHub.

I know Mac users in the class use X code to develop to our needs although some small issues arise with compilation that needs some debug work to be done.  Windows just isn't cutting it for me anymore...I've welcomed myself to the darkside...I'm wondering if Linux distros have any development tools that would be compatible to create and run these types of applications?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? And if not, are you asking if Cinder can be used on Ubuntu or are you just looking for a C++ development environment?

Answer (score 0):

I use NetBeans IDE. Which allows you to use C++ complier. But you have to configure it your self.

They have a wiki to show you how to do it.

here is the link: http://netbeans.org/features/cpp/

[Check this question if you have a problem in starting NetBeans from the dash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172208/ubuntu-12-04-and-netbeans-7-2)